# Is it possible to generate Class diagram/Architecture diagram using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an existing huge django 1.8 project which uses rest-framework and has about 90 models(tables). I'd like to generate a class diagram/architecture diagram for the tables. Is there any automated tool for this that I can use?

Swagger helped me to create API documentation and I've become a fan of django-rest-framework already.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the graph_models management command provided by django-extensions: https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html

This will greate a Graphviz dot file with your models and their relations - notice that you'll need Graphviz installed in order to view or convert it to png.